# Breeze navigation properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, odata, breeze

I have just started working with Breeze (using Angular) and have managed to get some data from my Odata service and displayed it on the page.  However, I now need to get a related field via a foreign key (I need to get Group related to a Team object) and I am having some difficulties.  Using datajs after version 1.0.3 causes issues so I am using version 1.0.3, but this version does not allow 'expand' to be used.  So instead I have disabled lazy loading in my model and used Include when getting in my controller :

```
public partial class Team
    {
        public int TeamId { get; set; }
        public string TeamName { get; set; }
        public string FlagSmall { get; set; }
        public string FlagLarge { get; set; }
        public string BadgeSmall { get; set; }
        public string BadgeLarge { get; set; }
        public string TeamImage { get; set; }

        //foreign key
        public int GroupId { get; set; }
        //navigation properties
        public Group Group { get; set; }  //virtual removed to disable lazy loading
    }

    // GET odata/Teams 
            [Queryable]
            public IQueryable<Team> GetTeams()
            {
                return db.Teams.Include("Groups");   //get navigation property
            }

            // GET odata/Teams(5)
            [Queryable]
            public SingleResult<Team> GetTeam([FromODataUri] int key)
            {
                return SingleResult.Create(db.Teams.Include("Groups").Where(team => team.TeamId == key));
            }
```

However, this does not work either, it gives a similar error to the error caused by > datajs 1.0.3 :

```
[Q] Unhandled rejection reasons (should be empty): ["createError@http://bras...s/datajs-1.0.3.js:1055\n"]
```

Has anybody got around this and managed to get related fields via a foreign key?

EDIT :

Here is my angular code, I have tried referring to team.Group.GroupName, team.GroupName, and group.GroupName, but neither of these works :

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="team in teams | filter:search:TeamName | orderBy:'TeamId'" id="team_{{team.id}}">
        <td>{{team.TeamId}}</td>
        <td>{{team.TeamName}}</td>
        <td><img src={{team.FlagSmall}}></img></td>
        <td><img style="width:40px;height:40px" src={{team.FlagLarge}}></img></td>
        <td><img style="width:40px;height:40px" src={{team.BadgeSmall}}></img></td>
        <td><img style="width:40px;height:40px" src={{team.BadgeLarge}}></img></td>
        <td><img style="width:80px;height:40px" src={{team.TeamImage}}></img></td>
        <td>{{team.Group.GroupName}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

EDIT 2 :

This is my Breeze query :

```
this.basicTeamQuery = function () {
    return manager.executeQuery(entityQuery.from("Teams")).to$q();
};
```

EDIT 3 :

After some experimenting I managed to get this working with the following Breeze query :

```
this.basicTeamQuery = function () {
    return manager.executeQuery(entityQuery.from("Teams").
        select("TeamId, TeamName, FlagSmall, FlagLarge, BadgeSmall, BadgeLarge, TeamImage, " +
        "Group.GroupName").expand("Group")).to$q();
};
```

Not sure if this is the correct way to do this, or even if it *should* work...isn't expand supposed to not work with Angular?

EDIT 4 :

Here is the final working query, no need for the select above :

```
this.basicTeamQuery = function () {
    return manager.executeQuery(entityQuery.from("Teams").
        expand("Group")).to$q();
};
```

Comment: Are you sure this error only rears its head when you are .Including the navigation property?  Sounds like a promise not being fulfilled to me...

Comment: Before I added the changes above (the Includes and removing the virtual keyword from the Group field of the model), it returned the data successfully

Comment: Please copy the breeze query that you are using to fetch data

Comment: Please see EDIT 2 above.  Do I need to add a join to the Groups table in the query in order to gain access to related Group info? Is it possible to even do this in Breeze as I guess Breeze uses expand for that purpose?

Comment: Didn't expand work without select?

Comment: Yes, tried it without the select and it worked.  So expand can be used with Angular?

Comment: Yes, it can be. Expand doesn't have anything to do with Angular, it is a Breeze query method which in turn maps to an OData URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried it and it worked for me without any issue.

I see a typo in the snippet you copied in the question. Name of your navigation property defined in the Item class is Group, but you passed "Groups" to the Include function. Can you try it by fixing the typo and update if you still face the issue?

UPDATE:
It seems you cannot get the navigation property without using expand. Because, even the OData URL without expand doesn't send values of navigation properties despite of using Include in the LINQ query.

Comment: Thanks, that at least prevents the error message...I thought I needed to refer to the collection (Groups) rather than the actual navigation property name (Group).  However, see my edit, as I thus far have not been able to bring through the GroupName from the Group in my angular code.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
    [ForeignKey("GroupId")]
    [InverseProperty("Teams")]
    public Group Group { get; set; }
```

EDIT:

After checking once again, I noticed that relationship is different than what I thought at first glance. Since one Group has MANY Teams, try query the other way:

```
        [Queryable]
        public IQueryable<Group> GetGroupsWithTeams()
        {
            return db.Groups.Include("Teams");   //get navigation property
        }
```

That should return everything properly.

Comment: This returns a default JSON error message 'an error has occured'

Comment: How would I call 'GetGroupsWithTeams' from a Breeze query?

Comment: `return manager.executeQuery(entityQuery.from("GroupsWithTeams")).to$q();` should work.